# Ragged list to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, ragged

I have a non-uniform list as follows:

```
[['E', 'A', 'P'],
 ['E', 'A', 'X', 'P'],
 ['E', 'A', 'P'],
 ['P'],
 ['E', 'A', 'X', 'P'],
 ['E', 'A', 'P'],
 ['A', 'X', 'P'],
 ['E', 'A', 'P'],
 ['E', 'A', 'P'],
 ['E', 'A', 'X', 'P'],
 ['E', 'A', 'P'],
 ['E', 'A', 'P'],
 ['A', 'X', 'P'],
```

I would like to create a data frame from this, where each column represents the four possible letters `"E"`, `"A"`, `"X"` and `"p"` in a one-hot encoded manner - what is the most efficient way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    ["E", "A", "P"],
    ["E", "A", "X", "P"],
    ["E", "A", "P"],
    ["P"],
    ["E", "A", "X", "P"],
    ["E", "A", "P"],
    ["A", "X", "P"],
    ["E", "A", "P"],
    ["E", "A", "P"],
    ["E", "A", "X", "P"],
    ["E", "A", "P"],
    ["E", "A", "P"],
    ["A", "X", "P"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame({v: 1 for v in l} for l in lst).notna().astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    E  A  P  X
0   1  1  1  0
1   1  1  1  1
2   1  1  1  0
3   0  0  1  0
4   1  1  1  1
5   1  1  1  0
6   0  1  1  1
7   1  1  1  0
8   1  1  1  0
9   1  1  1  1
10  1  1  1  0
11  1  1  1  0
12  0  1  1  1
```

Comment: You are a star, thank you will mark this as answer accepted!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `MultiLabelBinarizer` from `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
 
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(l),columns=mlb.classes_)
Out[170]: 
    A  E  P  X
0   1  1  1  0
1   1  1  1  1
2   1  1  1  0
3   0  0  1  0
4   1  1  1  1
5   1  1  1  0
6   1  0  1  1
7   1  1  1  0
8   1  1  1  0
9   1  1  1  1
10  1  1  1  0
11  1  1  1  0
12  1  0  1  1
```

Or we try pandas way with `explode` and `str.get_dummies`

```
df = pd.Series(l).explode().str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum()
Out[176]: 
    A  E  P  X
0   1  1  1  0
1   1  1  1  1
2   1  1  1  0
3   0  0  1  0
4   1  1  1  1
5   1  1  1  0
6   1  0  1  1
7   1  1  1  0
8   1  1  1  0
9   1  1  1  1
10  1  1  1  0
11  1  1  1  0
12  1  0  1  1
```

Notice `l` is your `list` here